# Git sees all my files from /PycharmProjects

Tags: git, pycharm

Recently I have faced a strange and annoying problem: working with git from PyCharm, git checks all the files and projects from my ~/PycharmProjects directory. It makes committing impossible since there are over 23k unresolved files there. I am still able to work from console with 'git add ...' but when it comes to big projects with many files, this is unbearable as well.

In .gitignore file it said that not all the ignored directories are excluded from indexing and search and presented a part of my projects. After I excluded them, there still was many projects left in indexing:
[excluding some projects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2AAum.png)
[still many projects left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CNgOp.png)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would suppose you created git repo in ~/PycharmProjects directory, the question is - why? One project/solution - one repo.

Comment: Oh I'll check maybe I did it accidentally, Thanks for pointing out!

Comment: Yes, this was actually the case, thank you so much